# Laravel 5.3 not logging in admins after changing redirect routes - multi auth

Tags: redirect, laravel-5.3, multi-user

Hi all, I implemented multi auth with laravel 5.3. but after changing the redirect routes so that the admin goes to admin dashboard after logging in, it stopped working. The admins don't login no matter what,they are bounced back to the login page.

```html
class AdminLoginController extends Controller
{
 public function __construct()
 {
  $this->middleware('guest:admin');
 }
    public function showLoginForm()
    {
     return view('auth.adminLogin');
    }
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
                'email' => 'required|email',
                'password' => 'required|min:5'
            ]);

        //I have checked and noticed that this if statement is never true. so it is never entered
        if(Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password], $request->remember))
        {
            dd('inside if'); // THIS IS NEVER EXECUTED :(
            return redirect()->intended(route('admin.dashboard'));
        }
        dd(Auth::guard());
        return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'));
    }
}
```

I expected  that to be executed and redirect the admin.

```html
//If not authenticated - redirects
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        if ($request->expectsJson()) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
        }
        $guard = array_get($exception->guards(), 0);
        switch ($guard) {
            case 'admin':
                $login = 'admin.login';
                break;                 
            default:
                $login = 'login';
                break;
        }
        return redirect()->guest(route($login));
    }
```

In the admin controller I have:

```html
class AdminController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:admin');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('admin.index');
    }
}
```

The redirect if unauthenticated class:

```html
class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
     public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        // if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        //     return redirect('auth/login');
        // }
        switch ($guard) {
            case 'admin':
                if(Auth::guard($guard)->check())
                {
                    return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard'); //auth:login
                }
                break;
            
            default:
                if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                    return redirect('/');
                }
                break;
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

And the admin routes

```html
Route::get('/admin/login', 'Auth\AdminLoginController@showLoginForm')->name('admin.login');
Route::post('/admin/login', 'Auth\AdminLoginController@login')->name('admin.login.submit');
Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@index')->name('admin.dashboard');
```

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: is it failing validation and just redirecting back ... since it is never reaching that `if` block, seems an exception is being thrown or its not even making to that controller method at all ... remove the `$this->validate(...)` call and see what happens

Comment: no its making it that far, it just does not enter the if block. the dd(Auth::guard()); is always executed but the one inside is never executed. the validation works fine. that has no problem. but am afraid its the auth. the admin guard is not seen at all or just returns false.